# Call to a member function posts() on null

Tags: php, laravel

> FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to a member function posts() on
>   null

PostsController.php file

```
$imagePath=(request('image')->store('upload','public'));
  $image=Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
  $image->save();

auth()->user()->posts()->create(['caption' => $data['caption'],'image'=> $imagePath,
```

Comment: It means that `auth()->user()` is not giving you a user object. What does `var_dump(auth()->user())` give you?

Comment: I don't understand what are you say?

Comment: Add at the beginning of your code `dd(auth()->user())` and tell us what it returns.

Comment: how did you define the models relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember if your controller involves users. You should make sure that the controller uses middleware `auth`. So if the user is not logged in, the controller won't instantiate and user will be redirected to login page. if you don't specify this you might face this error because even unathenticated users can access the controller. And therefore `auth()->user()` returns null.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Also, take a careful look to your `one to many` relationship between Post and User Model

Answer (score 0):

try to dump

```
dd(auth()->user());
```

and see if it returns you curently logged in user or not.

If not working, then try to log out and log in again to your application.
Else try:

```
Auth::user()
```

instead of

```
auth()->user()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check auth with middleware

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

And use;

```
Auth::user()
```

Answer (score -1):

Call to a member function `Posts()` on `null`  in Laravel 7

[see code screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyKou.png)

Comment: If could could include the text of of your code rather than an image, that would tremendously improve your answer